# Including XML format in WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl, java-7, soap-client, wsdl2java

My method signature is displayed below:

```
public String test(@WebParam(name = "INPUTPACKET") String inputPacket)
```

the problem being the inputPacket parameter accepts an XML and the WSDL file structure displays inputPacket as string type so how do I get the WSDL to accommodate the  XML structure which I want my input packet to contain

I've tried manually editing the WSDL to accommodate the XML structure and then sending the a API call to my method but it fails show the error as below:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"RESPONSEPACKET"). Expected elements are (none)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a SOAP service, `string` could have `XML`. The only thing you have to make sure that you `escape` the `XML` properly, either using `[CDATA]`[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).

As an example, your XML will look like this-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
<soap:Body>
  <m:GetPrice xmlns:m="https://www.w3schools.com/prices">
    <m:example>
<![CDATA[<data>
 XML Example
</data>]]></m:example>
  </m:GetPrice>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

There is another alternative as well, but above one is better.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
<soap:Body>
  <m:GetPrice xmlns:m="https://www.w3schools.com/prices">
    <m:example>
&lt;data&gt;
 XML Example
&lt;/data&gt;</m:example>
  </m:GetPrice>
</soap:Body>
```

Most of XML parser and XML libraries support this special character `escaping` and `remove escaping`.

**Update based on comment:**
Yes, if you want to even provide the `XML` definition for `body`(i.e. [XSD](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_howto.asp)), you could do that.
Here is brief approach.

```
<GetPrice   xmlns="https://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.example.com/xml/price.xsd"></GetPrice>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: @vlemaistre I totally get it how to send the response but my exact problem is that , I want my WSDL file to show the XML packet structure so that person consuming the SOAP API need not to be sent the XML packet explicitly , and that I'm not able to do